# (Postgresql) How to get all match from array of integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want all row matching with group_id pass as input

ex.

Here is my table:-

```
id |      name      | group_id 
----+----------------+----------
  1 | Alice John     | {1,2,3}
  2 | joshn shukla   | {1,4}
  3 | rishikesh jain | {2,8}
```

when I execute below query:-

```
select * from employee where group_id::TEXT ~ '[\{,]2,8[,\}]'
```

then it returns result become

```
 id |      name      | group_id 
----+----------------+----------
  3 | rishikesh jain | {2,8}
```

expected  result all match:-

```
 id |      name      | group_id 
----+----------------+----------
  1 | Alice John     | {1,2,3}
  3 | rishikesh jain | {2,8}
```

because 2 present in both rows.
any solution ?

Comment: I removed the conflicting version tags (two versions being on longer supported). Please add only one tag for the version you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from employee  where  (group_id  && '{2,8}');
```

Comment: Is there any solution like   In query because this passed input is dynamic, so if input is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 then we need to create 8 or conditions.

Comment: I have updated my answer with one single condition.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be using regular expressions to get comma-seperated substrings as rows, and then extract the digits only by using

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT e.*, 
        regexp_replace(regexp_split_to_table(group_id, E','),'[^[:digit:]]','','g')::int
             AS num
   FROM employees e
)
SELECT DISTINCT id, group_id
  FROM t
 WHERE num IN (2,8)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=f2583e0f8b18923da662a59f981affed)</kbd>

Comment: It work's but complex solution.
Anyway thank you buddy... :)